# Row subsets of `Tibble` loses custom s3 class

Tags: r, dataframe, tidyverse, tibble

If I extract a row from a dataframe, my custom s3 class stays:

```
test_df = iris

class(test_df) <- c("test_class", class(test_df))

class(test_df[1,])
[1] "test_class" "data.frame"
```

But this does not work for tibbles:

```
test_df <- as_tibble(test_df)
class(test_df) <- c("test_class", class(test_df))
class(test_df[1,])
[1] "tbl_df"     "tbl"        "data.frame"
```

Is there a way around this?
Thanks

Comment: I guess you could implement a `"["` method for `test_class`.

Comment: There is some discussion about it [here](https://github.com/tidyverse/tibble/issues/155) and [here](https://github.com/tidyverse/tibble/issues/275).

Comment: Yeah thanks you need a `[` method and a class constructor function. I'm answering my own question right now

Comment: Also discussion [here](https://github.com/tidyverse/tibble/issues/155#issuecomment-242862857).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer comes from the s3 section of Hadley's [Advanced R book](https://adv-r.hadley.nz/s3.html). You have to define a class constructor function and a new `[` function.

```
new_test <- function(x, ...) {

  structure(x, class = c("test_class", class(x)))
}

`[.test_class` <- function(x, ...) {
  new_test(NextMethod())
}

test_df <- iris
test_df <- as_tibble(test_df)
class(test_df) <- c("test_class", class(test_df))
class(test_df[1,])
[1] "tbl_df"     "tbl"        "data.frame"
```